# How to unit test POJO which uses Android SDK classes on JVM?

Tags: android, junit, jvm, mocking, stub

I have a Java class called **Warehouse** which is using Android's [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html). When trying to unit test it, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
```

The class looks like that:

```
public class Warehouse {
    private Bundle items;

    public Warehouse(Bundle items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
}
```

In the unit test I have the following:

```
void testInitializeWarehouse() {
     Bundle items = new Bundle();
     Warehouse wh = new Warehouse(items);
     assertNotNull(wh);
}
```

When I run the test I get **java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!** 
I know this issue is related to me running the unit test on JVM rather than Dalvik VM, but is there a way to run this unit test on JVM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out [Robolectric](http://pivotal.github.io/robolectric/), which is exactly what I was looking for. I could have used mocks but then half of the unit tests will consist of mocks setups etc.

> "a unit test framework that de-fangs the Android SDK jar so you can
>   test-drive the development of your Android app. Tests run inside the
>   JVM on your workstation in seconds."

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Powermock` to mock `Bundle` using its ability to mock a final class as described [here - Powermock MockFinal](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockFinal)

Comment: That would probably work in this case, where the dependency is injected to the method. But what about situations where I instantiate Android classes directly in the POJO? It wouldn't work.